# How to get selected profiles for the Communities workspaces

Tags: soql, profile, community-builder

I have create `Communities` and I'm trying to query to find out what are the `Selected Profiles` for that communities workspaces.

I was able to find the profile by querying:

`SELECT Id, Name From Profile Where Name = 'Partner Community User'`

But I couldn't able to find out how to find profile by `Communities workspaces`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a query on NetworkMemberGroup object.

Query all Profiles/Permission Sets related to a single community:

> SELECT ParentId, Parent.Name FROM NetworkMemberGroup where NetworkId='network id'

Query all Community related to a single Profile (If profile name is provided):

> SELECT NetworkId FROM NetworkMemberGroup where ParentId IN (SELECT id
>   from Profile where profile.name = 'System Administrator')

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_networkmembergroup.htm

Comment: how would you do the profile.name check?

Comment: See my updated response... U can add where parent.name = 'name of profle'

Comment: Ramadan Mubark :) - `Parent.Name` getting error don't understand relationship `Parent`, I don't think we can get that in one query, needs to do it multiple query.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Just realized that ParentId is lookup on Profile as well as Permission set ...So does not return any specific field...You may need to do second query after getting id

Comment: @NickKahn ..updated my answer to query based on  profile name...Thanks for wishing Ramdan..It means a lot to me!